# Process Memory (MB) keeps going up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, closedxml

I have a code that runs the code below:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = txtPath.Text;
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(txtWorksheet.Text);
        var cells = worksheet.Range(txtMinRange.Text+":"+txtMaxRange.Text).Cells();

            foreach (var c in cells)
            {
                if (c.Value == "")
                {
                    c.Value = "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    c.Value = c.Value;
                }

            }

        workbook.SaveAs("RowCells.xlsx");
        workbook.Dispose();
    }
```

What it does is, it change all blank cells given a range in an excel file into dash "-" and save it to another file named RowCells.

However looking at the Memory usage, it keeps getting higher until the Application goes into break mode.

How can I keep the Memory Usage down?

Comment: `worksheet` also implements `IDisposable` so maybe you should dispose it too.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the memory usage is related to the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks as it should work, but your input spreadsheet might be very large.
Anyway, I don't know how ClosedXML works internally, but it might keep a list of changed cells. Since you are changing every cell in the range, that might get very large, you should only change the cells that need changing. Do something like this:

```cs
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string path = txtPath.Text;
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
    using (var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(txtWorksheet.Text))
    {
        var cells = worksheet.Range(txtMinRange.Text+":"+txtMaxRange.Text).Cells();
        foreach (var c in cells)
        {
            if (c.Value == "")
            {
                c.Value = "-";
            }
        }
    }
    workbook.SaveAs("RowCells.xlsx");
    workbook.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah I believe this is because the file is too large. I'm trying to process 17,000 Rows with Columns from A-KC. I tried using your code then after 2 hours, it showed OutOfMemoryException.